# Why in salesforce can't track specific fields?

Tags: history-tracking

I found only information that I can not track history in a specific fields:

```
Formula, 
roll-up summary, 
auto-number,
Created By,
Last Modified By
```

Unfortunately I never found hints why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is limitation by Salesforce. The reasoning for these may be:

**Formula, roll-up summary:**
These are calculated in real time, when the record is viewed or queried. So, the history tracking is not reasonable since many viewers see the record, but not actually modify it. This gets calculated by Salesforce

**auto-number, Created By:**
These are populated only once, when the record is created

**Last Modified By:** This has specific purpose to just display the last user who modified the record. And it can not be modified by any user.

In a nutshell, these are system calculated fields. And not specific to User. The history can be tracked for the details that the Users can change.

Answer (score 2):

Those fields can't directly be changed by a user, so it doesn't make sense to have tracking on them

In the case of Formula, it is derived each time it is viewed. If the formula is based on other fields, you could track those.

Created By and Modified By are either set by the system or by Salesforce directly in the case of an initial load.